# What is causing my program to crash?

Tags: c, pointers, crash, runtime-error

I am intentionally printing an output of an uninitialized pointer to a character. Like this...

```
printf("%c, *pointer);
```

Many times, I get a random character, and when I declare new variables in the program, the character outputs change. Now, I run the program and the program crashes before it can enter the character that the pointer points to. What is causing the program to crash?

I checked the memory address value, its value is something like 2147880420 or something.

I'm a noob with programming and I just started learning pointers, I just don't understand what causes the program to crash.

No hate or BS like "don't do that, it's stupid", I am experimenting and learning and wish to understand.

Comment: Make sure you close off the quote just after the %c. Considering your program crashed, instead of running into a compile error, suggests it might be a typo, but should be checked anyway

Answer (score 3):

When a pointer is uninitialized, it's pointing to an invalid address. When you try to access the object it is pointing to, your program crashes. That is to be expected.

Comment: Good catch, I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing quote:

You have:

```
printf("%c, *pointer);
```

instead of:

```
printf("%c", *pointer);
```

(as pointed out above, this is probably a typo for the question, whoops)

Whenever you do anything with uninitialized variables, you will have undefined results because you are pointing at a random block of memory that could have anything in it from 0's to the white house's red telephone number to the secret of life, the universe and everything.